# Add Attribute to XML Node Using groovy-wslite

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using groovy-wslite for making SOAP calls to a WSDL and need one of the xml nodes that it generates to have an attribute. Here is an example of what I need:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
  <soap-env:Header />
  <soap-env:Body>
  <getSomething id = "1">
  </getSomething>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

In this example, I need the `getSomething` call to have the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides a closure that will build out child elements, you can also pass a map whose key/values will become attributes.  The following would generate a SOAP request matching what you have.

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='0.7.1')
import wslite.soap.*

def client = new SOAPClient('http://...')
def response = client.send {
    header
    body {
        getSomething(id:'1') {
            //more elements here if needed
        }
    }
}
```

Groovy's MarkupBuilder is used under the hood, so any examples you find for MarkupBuilder should also apply when generating SOAP requests with wslite.